# Determine the number of parameters of ARIMA models for AIC calculation

Tags: arima, aic, degrees-of-freedom

It is my understanding of the AIC formula that:
$$
AIC = -2\log(L) + 2m
$$
where $m =$ number of parameters.

I am wondering how to determine the value of $m$ in AIC for the following models:

- AR(1)
- MA(1)
- ARMA(1,1)
- ARIMA(1,1,1)
- Seasonal ARIMA(1,1,1)(1,1,1)12

I believe for an AR(p) model $m=p$,
MA(q) model $m=q$,
ARMA(p,q) model $m = p+q$,
ARIMA(p,d,q) model $m=p+q$
and for a seasonal ARIMA(p,d,q)(P,D,Q)s model $m = p+q+P+Q+1$.

Could you please let me know if this is correct?
And if not, how would I determine the correct number of parameters ($m$)?

Comment: I think it's mostly right, although perhaps +1 should be added everywhere (except for SARIMA) because of the fact that also $\sigma^2_{\varepsilon}$ is being estimated extra to the AR and MA coefficients. But I am not sure. Also, what is your logic behind the +1 for SARIMA but not in the other cases?

Comment: @RIchard The +1 is correct but nothing is lost by ignoring it with AIC (since they all have it). For BIC and AICc though, you can't just leave it out. Also you usually have a mean but for differenced models you often don't

Comment: @Glen, thanks. I presume you mean that nothing is lost in comparisons where such constants cancel out. But if one takes AIC of a given (as opposed to chosen) model and interprets it as the expected likelihood, then it starts to matter, right?

Comment: Yes, nothing is lost in comparisons when it's common to both.

Comment: I actually thought the +1 was for the seasonal component of the  seasonal ARIMA model. My interest is finding the exact number of parameters, so I do not want to leave out any additional parameters just for the ease of comparison.

Answer (score 6):

I think you are *almost* right. For a general SARIMA model, it would be
$$
m=p+q+P+Q+1
$$
where $+1$ comes from the fact that also $\sigma^2_{\varepsilon}$ is being estimated extra to the AR and MA coefficients.

For submodels such as AR, MA or ARIMA, just set the appropriate coefficients to zero. Thus $m=p+1$ for AR; $m=q+1$ for MA; and $m=p+q+1$ for ARIMA.

(As @Glen_b notes, the $+1$ is not so important when we compare AICs across models; when we take a difference between two AICs, the $+1$ in each cancels out.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I was testing your answer on R by running the following code:

    arima(dowjones,c(1,0,0)).

This resulted in R outputting a log likelihood of -49.86 and an aic of 105.72. Doing some basic maths with the AIC formula and the loglikelihood, R output is suggesting that the number of parameters is 3 rather than 2 (your suggested answer).

Comment: I don't know if the reported likelihood is correct. It will be correct up to a constant but probably not beyond that. I find it annoying, but that is how most of the functions do it...

Comment: I believe it is correct since -49.86*-2 = 99.72. Indicating exactly 6 needs to be added on to achieve the correct AIC. This indicates that the correct number of parameters is 3. Should I perhaps post this as a separate question with the R code included?

Comment: Perhaps the constant counts as a parameter as well? I don't know...